# Create an arbitrary FAT filesystem, to file or directly in program memory

Tags: c, macos, usb, fat, usb-mass-storage

I am writing an embedded system, where I am creating a USB mass storage device driver that uses an 8MB chunk of RAM as the FAT fileystem..

Although it made sense at the time to allow the OS to take my zero'd out RAM area and format a FAT partition itself, I ran into problems that I am diagnosing on Jan Axelson's (popular author of books on USB) [PORTS forum](http://janaxelson.com/forum/index.php?topic=1454.0). The problem is related to erasing the blocks in the drive, and may be circumvented by pre-formatting the memory area to a FAT filesystem before USB enumeration. Then, I could see if the drive will operate normally. Ideally, the preformatted partition would include a file on it to test the read operation.

It would be nice if I could somehow create and mount a mock 8MB FAT filesystem on my OS (OSX), write a file to it, and export it to an image file for inclusion in my project. Does someone know how to do this? I could handle the rest. I'm not too concerned whether that would be FAT12/16/32 at the moment, optional MBR inclusion would be nice..

If that option doesn't exist, I'm looking to use a pre-written utility to create a FAT img file that I could include into my project and upload directly to RAM. this utility would allow me to specify an 8MB filesystem with 512-byte sectors, for instance, and possibly FAT12 / FAT16 / FAT32.

Is anyone aware of such a utility? I wasn't able to find one.

If not, can someone recommend a first step to take in implementing this in C? I'm hoping a library exists. I'm pretty exhausted after implementing the mass storage driver from scratch, but I understand I might have to 'get crinkled' and manually create the FAT partition. It's not too hard. I imagine some packed structs and some options. I'll get there. I already have resources on FAT filesystem itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up discovering that [FatFS](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html) has facilities for formatting and partitioning the "drive" from within the embedded device, and it relieved of me of having to absolutely format it manually or use host-side tools.

I would like to cover in more detail the steps taken, but I am exhausted. I may edit in further details at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

There are several, they're normally hidden in the OS source.

On BSD (ie OS-X) you should have a "mkdosfs" tool, if not the source will be available all over the place ... here's a random example

http://www.blancco.com/downloads/source/utils/mkdosfs/mkdosfs.c

Also there's the 'mtools' package, it's normally use for floppies, but I think it does disk images too.

Neither of these will create partition tables though; you'd need something else if that's required too.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will be required.. Although I only plan on having a single partition, which would insinuate no need for a partition table, Jan Axelson's book does state that having an MBR may increase support for the device.. Your thoughts?

Comment: currently looking at [mformat](http://www.gnu.org/software/mtools/manual/mtools.html#mformat)